# PKCS #7 encryptedDigest decryption and validation using Windows Crypto API and C++

Tags: c++, windows, encryption, cryptoapi

#### Intro

I am trying to perform the following operation to check certificate's **SignedData.SignerInfo.encryptedDigest**:

```
1) Read
SignedData.contentInfo +
SignedData.SignerInfo.authenticatedAttributes

2) Calculate Hash of contentInfo and authenticatedAttributes
using SignedData.digestAlgorithm

3) Read SignerInfo.encryptedDigest and certificate's PUBLIC key

4) Decrypt encryptedDigest using the acquired key
(it is the problem, and the question is about this)

5) Compare decryptedDigest's hash
with hash of contentInfo and authenticatedAttributes (STEP 2)
```

#### The problem

I tried a different ways to RSA-decrypt **encryptedDigest** with certificate's **public key** using **Windows Crypto API**, but each of them brings to error.

#### Attempt #1 to solve

Tried to use **CryptDecrypt**
Result: error **2148073485** (Key does not exist)
Please see the failing code below (sample #1).
Brief search tells, that the API doesn't allow to use **public key** for **decryption**.
If it is wrong, please give me a hint how to do it.

#### Attempt #2 to solve

Tried to use **CryptVerifySignature**
Result: error **87** (The parameter is incorrect)
Please see the failing code below (sample #2).
Tried to change the code in a several ways, but still could not find out the reason of invalid parameter error returning
What's wrong in the sample #2 ?

#### Other

I don't need a high-level functions, which perform a lot of other operations besides the required RSA decryption due to performance requirements.
It is also not desirable to use OpenSSL or other crypto libraries

#### Code Sample #1 (CryptDecrypt)

```
// certPublicKey = certContext->pCertInfo->SubjectPublicKeyInfo.PublicKey.pbData[.cbData]
const size_t StructSize = sizeof(BLOBHEADER) + sizeof(RSAPUBKEY) + certPublicKey.size();
boost::scoped_array<uint8_t> arr(new uint8_t[StructSize]);
BLOBHEADER* pHeader = (BLOBHEADER*)&arr[0];
pHeader->bType = PUBLICKEYBLOB;
pHeader->bVersion = CUR_BLOB_VERSION;
pHeader->reserved = 0;
pHeader->aiKeyAlg = CALG_RSA_KEYX;

RSAPUBKEY* pPubKey = (RSAPUBKEY*)&arr[sizeof(BLOBHEADER)];
pPubKey->magic = 0x31415352;
pPubKey->bitlen = certPublicKey.size() * 8;
pPubKey->pubexp = 65537; // ?? is it correct for RSA ?

uint8_t* pKeyData = &arr[sizeof(BLOBHEADER) + sizeof(RSAPUBKEY)];
memcpy(pKeyData, &certPublicKey[0], certPublicKey.size());

HCRYPTKEY hKey;
BOOL res = CryptImportKey(g_hProv, (const BYTE*)&arr[0], StructSize, NULL, 0, &hKey);
PRINT_RES("CryptImportKey", res);
if (res)
{
    blob_t decryptedData = encryptedText;
    DWORD decryptedLength = encryptedText.size();
    res = CryptDecrypt(hKey, NULL, TRUE, 0, decryptedData.data(), &decryptedLength);
    PRINT_RES("CryptDecrypt", res); // err = 2148073485 (Key does not exist)
    if (res)
    {
        ...
    }

    res = CryptDestroyKey(hKey);
    PRINT_RES("CryptDestroyKey", res);
}
```

#### Code Sample #2 (CryptVerifySignature)

```
// hashInput = SignedData.contentInfo + SignedData.SignerInfo[0].authenticatedAttributes
HCRYPTHASH hHash;
blob_t hashValue;

BOOL res = CryptCreateHash(g_hProv, CALG_SHA1, NULL, 0, &hHash);
PRINT_RES("CryptCreateHash", res);

if (res)
{
    res = CryptHashData(hHash, hashInput.data(), hashInput.size(), 0);
    PRINT_RES("CryptHashData", res);

    PCCERT_CONTEXT certContext = CertCreateCertificateContext(X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, certData.data(), certData.size());
    PRINT_RES("CertCreateCertificateContext", certContext ? TRUE : FALSE);
    if (certContext)
    {
        HCRYPTKEY hCertPubKey;
        res = CryptImportPublicKeyInfo(g_hProv, X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, &certContext->pCertInfo->SubjectPublicKeyInfo, &hCertPubKey);
        PRINT_RES("CryptImportPublicKeyInfo", res);
        if (res)
        {
            res = CryptVerifySignatureA(hHash, encryptedText.data(), encryptedText.size(), hCertPubKey, NULL, 0);
            PRINT_RES("CryptVerifySignature", res); // err = 87 (The parameter is incorrect)

            res = CryptDestroyKey(hCertPubKey);
            PRINT_RES("CryptDestroyKey", res);
        }

        CertFreeCertificateContext(certContext);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `encryptedDigest` contains a signature, you don't decrypt it but verify the signature, so your second avenue of `CryptVerifySignature` is the promising one.

There could be multiple things that can go wrong here, for example you don't really tell us anything about the certificate. Please follow [Example C Program: Encoding and Decoding a Countersigned Message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382050%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN where you would be interested in `CryptVerifyMessageSignature` in step #2,

```
...
// From the recipient's point of view, the following code 
// completes these steps: 
//     1.  Decodes the message
//     2.  Verifies the signature on the message
//     3.  Adds a countersignature to the signed message
//
...
```

towards the second part of the example.